# Create Google Play Developer account using domain email or g suite account

Tags: android, gmail, google-workspace, google-play-console

I need to create **google play developer account** for an **organization** to publish an android app.

Now, I have some questions regarding creating **google play developer account** either by **g suite account** or **personal google account** using current email. [Example for Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2knUw.png)

### G Suite Account

- If I create g suite account than the process for creating google play developer account will be similar just like for personal google account ?

### Personal Google Account

- If I already have an organizational email and creates google personal account using that organizational email then which google apps do I be able to use? [Creating google account just like shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2knUw.png)
- Also, if my account is on outlook, then do my emails will send or receive using gmail or on same outlook after creating google account for personal?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Still interested in the answer to this, this was the first hit on a Google search. Why pay $100 for 4 devs (plus the constant rotation of new ones) when you can pay $25 for a single dev org account? I tried using a Google Group email but that didn't work